# Is that the Jquery.validate.rules("add",{.....}) bugged?

Tags: jquery-validate

```
//html  
<form id="idform">  
  <input id="id_t_email">  
  <input id="id_p_password" type="password">  
</form>  

//js
$('#idform').validate();
$('#id_t_email').rules('add',{email:true});
$('#id_p_password').rules('add',{required:true});
```

I encounter a strange problem.
As the code above, there should be only a "email" validation for 'id_t_email', and only a "required" validation for id_p_password.
But in fact both "id_p_password" and "id_t_email" validated by both "email" and "required" at the same time.
furthermore, if I call

```
$('#id_t_email').rules('add',{email:true});
$('#id_p_password').rules('add',{email:false});
```

then the rule "email" of all fields will be remove
(that is, "id_t_email" will no more be validate by "email")
Is that a critical bug?

Comment: Well, I solved this question after study the source code.

The main problem is: all $.validate fields require their own "name".

This plugin use element.name as the index of all the validate fields

That is, if a element has no name attribute and there would be some strange problems.

Answer (score 0):

The `.validate()` plugin requires that each `input` contain a `name` attribute...

```
<input id="id_t_email" name="id_t_email" type="text" />  
<input id="id_p_password" name="id_p_password" type="password" />
```

You were also missing a `type` attribute on your first `input`.

See documentation:  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation